# DataGridView not displaying values using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq

It's very simple for the user.

They select the type of part, manufacturer from a ComboBox, and search the part code in a text box. Click search and the results return in a DataGridView.

Code:

```
var mType = CmbType.SelectedItem.ToString();
var mManufacturer = CmbMfr.SelectedValue.ToString();
var mCode = Convert.ToString(TxtProductCode.Text);

switch (mType)
{
    case "Faucets":
        var faucets = Resources.Accessor.SearchFaucets(mManufacturer, mCode);
        DgInventory.DataSource = faucets;
        break;
    case "Parts":
        var parts = Resources.Accessor.SearchParts(mManufacturer, mCode);
        DgInventory.DataSource = parts;
        break;
}
```

Accessor Code:

```
public static List<TblFaucets> SearchFaucets(string mId, string mCode)
{
    var dataConnect = new PxLinqSqlDataContext();

    return (from f in dataConnect.GetTable<TblFaucets>()
            where (f.Mfr == Convert.ToInt32(mId))
            where (f.Code == mCode)
            select f).ToList<TblFaucets>();
    }
```

What "messes up" is the results:

- ID: correct
- Mfr: is the ID from its table, not the name
- Code: Correct
- Description: correct
- Price: correct
- Date: correct
- Manufacturer: I don't know why this is even here, its result is "PXDB.TblManufacturers

Comment: can you show your datagridview code?

Comment: The datagridview code is basically 
DgInventory.MultiSelect = false;
DgInventory.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

Otherwise its pretty bare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `PXDB.TblManufacturers` seems to be a **relation** from *tblFaucets to tblManufactureres*.
`Mfr` seems to be the **foreignKey** value within your faucets table refering to a manufacturer.

You may try creating an **anonymous type** holding only those data you want to. Within your select clause pick your data - as well as any relational data.

```
public static List<DisplayFaucet> SearchFaucets(string mId, string mCode)
{
    var dataConnect = new PxLinqSqlDataContext();

    return (from f in dataConnect.GetTable<TblFaucets>()
        where (f.Mfr == Convert.ToInt32(mId))
        where (f.Code == mCode)
        select new DisplayFaucet () {                              // create anonymous object 
                  ID = f.ID,                      // only holding the data you want to
                  Manufacturer = Manufacturer.Name,  // assuming there is property Name within your manufacturer table?!
                  Code = f.Code,
                  Description = f.Description,
                  Price = f.Price,
                  Date = f.Date
               }).ToList();
}
```

Add another class to hold your data to display

```
public class DisplayFaucet
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; } // check type
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public doublePrice{ get; set; } // check type
    public DaetTime Date { get; set; } // check type
}
```

Note that `SearchFaucets(..)` may no longer return items of type **tblFaucet**! Instead I created a new class. This one contains all data which should be displayed!

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the relation between the two tables.  Let me clarify, I believe I DO need it to return items because back on the form I am calling the SearchFaucets() method with the variables mId, and mCode.  Without it, I'm not sure how to reliably do a search?

Comment: The compiler complains the method must have a return type.  I edited my previous msg.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps as I am new to this, but i'm using straight up LINQ only.  I have no "members" such as {get; set;}.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: Your code worked!  However, I had to change the query a bit, is this the most efficient way to do this code?

Comment: I don't understand why my modified keeps getting killed off so I'll add it here, in the return block I had to add "where (f.Mfr == m.IdManufacturer)" so it could associate with the correct Name.